# Camera settings (brightness, saturation) on Catalina

Tags: settings, camera, webcam

Been a videoconference power-user for ~10 years, and I really like to adjust brightness and saturation on the camera (whether it is laptop camera, external webcam, etc).

Is there any app or tool in current OSX (ie: Catalina) that can do this?

Background:

Until Catalina, I was a happy user of Sight Control (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/sight-control/id528980445), which could adjust the settings on the camera atop my Apple Thunderbolt monitor and on the laptop camera. With Catalina, either APIs have moved, or permissions tightened and it doesn't work anymore :-/

On Catalina, Webcam Settings Control (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630) works for the Apple Thunderbolt display camera, but not on the camera on the laptop.